# APC Cache Adapter - Unique?

Tags: zend-framework2

Perhaps I'm just not fully understanding the documentation right now but is there a way to set a unique identifier so my cached translations are not being overwritten?

Each domain has the same namespace.

Here is what I have so far in my module.config.php

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale'                    => 'en',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'        => 'gettext',
            'base_dir'    => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'     => '%s.mo',
            'text_domain' => 'ftp'
        )
    ),
    'cache' => \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory(array(
        'adapter' => 'apc',
        'plugins' => array(
            'exception_handler' => array(
                'throw_exceptions' => false
            )
        )
    ))
)
```

Now I have two Apache VirtualHosts running on the same machine and in each VirtualHost I have a module named Ftp and each of those modules uses the ftp text_domain to translate their own translations.

Let's say I have a translation key named translate_this_text which is used on both domains.

On domain1.com it would read, Test1
on domain2.com it would read, Test2

If I access domain1.com the text is translated to Test1
If I access domain2.com the text is translated to Test1, but this should be Test2

If I clear the APC Cache and access domain2.com then the translation shows Test2 but then if I access domain1.com it shows Test2.

I hope that wasn't too confusing.

So in the end, is there a way to set some type of unique identifier on each host so they don't overwrite each other since they exist on the same machine right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `adapter` value by an array so you can inject options into the APC adapter:

```
'translator' => array(
    'cache' => \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory(array(
        'adapter' => array(
            'name'    => 'apc',
            'options' => array(
                'namespace' => 'foo_bar',
            ),
        ),
        'plugins' => array(
            'exception_handler' => array(
                'throw_exceptions' => false
            )
        )
    ))
)
```

I would write above config **without** `namespace` key in your global file and then your `config.local.php` you add this rule:

```
$cache_namespace = 'foo_bar';

'translator' => array(
    'cache' => \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory(array(
        'adapter' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'namespace' => $cache_namespace,
            ),
        ),
    ))
)
```

For every application you can simply edit your local config file and have the global cache options shared.